# IOS Autolayout- Multiple images in one horizontal line of subview programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a tableview header and added a subview to it.
I am trying to center multiple avatar images(fixed width and height) in a single line of this ui subview.

Max number of images=max(predefined).
Number of images that I would like to fit is n.

When 5 is max number of image,

n=1:

[......................image 1........................... ]

n=2:

[.................image 1.....image2...............]

n=3

[.........image 1.....image2....image3.........]

n=4

[...image 1....image2....image3......image4...]

n=5

[.imag 1....imag2....imag3....imag4....imag5.]

That is the placement should be centred with equal spacings.

How can I achieve this programatically?

I can do this by story board, by placing max images in a row, keeping equal leading and trailing spaces,
and when n=1, i will hide 1,2,4 and 5

while when n=2, i will hide 1,2,5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can target a Deployment Target of iOS 9 and up, use `UIStackView`.  It's designed to handle this scenario.

If you can't do that yet, the following algorithm will work.  It doesn't use constraints.

```
CGFloat tableWidth = ...; // This may change if you allow rotation.
CGFloat spacer = ...; // Amount of space between images goes here.
CGFloat imageWidth = images.count > 0 ? [[images[0] size] width] : 0.0;
CGFloat imageHeight = images.count > 0 ? [[images[0] size] height] : 0.0;
CGFloat totalWidth = images.count * imageWidth + (images.count - 1) * spacer;
CGFloat leftEdge = (tableWidth / 2.0) - (totalWidth / 2.0);

for (int i = 0; i < images.count; i++) {
    UIImageView *iv = ...; // Create and configure with image[i].

    CGRect frame = CGMakeRect(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    frame.origin.x = leftEdge + (i * imageWidth + i * spacer);
    iv.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: Looks like this will work. A slight error in calculating left edge. I think it should be: `CGFloat leftEdge = (tableWidth/2) - (totalWidth / 2.0);`

Comment: You're correct.  That's what you get for working it out in your head for a SO answer, without actually trying it :)